# does eigen have self transpose multiply optimization like H.transpose()*H

Tags: optimization, eigen, matrix-multiplication, neon

I have browsed the tutorial of eigen at 
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialMatrixArithmetic.html

it said 
"Note: for BLAS users worried about performance, expressions such as c.noalias() -= 2 * a.adjoint() * b; are fully optimized and trigger a single gemm-like function call."

but how about computation like H.transpose() * H , because it's result is a symmetric matrix so it should only need half time as normal A*B, but in my test, H.transpose() * H spend same time as H.transpose() * B. does eigen have special optimization for this situation , like opencv, it has similar function.

I know symmetric optimization will break the vectorization , I just want to know if eigen have solution which could provide both symmetric optimization and vectorization

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, you need to tell Eigen that the result is symmetric this way:

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXd H = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(m,n);
Eigen::MatrixXd Z = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(n,n);
Z.template selfadjointView<Eigen::Lower>().rankUpdate(H.transpose());
```

The last line computes `Z += H * H^T` within the lower triangular part. The upper part is left unchanged. You want a full matrix, then copy the lower part to the upper one:

```cpp
Z.template triangularView<Eigen::Upper>() = Z.transpose();
```

This `rankUpdate` routine is fully vectorized and comparable to the BLAS equivalent. For small matrices, better perform the full product.

See also the respective [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__QuickRefPage.html#title15).

Comment: this is definitely what I want , I have test it correct , but in my test I think
Z.sefladjointView<Lower>().rankUpdate(H);
mean
Z+= H*H'
am I right ?

Comment: Right, if you want H'*H, then call  `.rankUpdate(H.adjoint());`.

Comment: sorry to bother you again :) I have met a problem compute H*A*H' , which A = A' , so is there any method to accelerate it ?

Comment: You can compute `B=H*A` as usual, then `Z.triangularView<Lower>() = B*H'`. This will compute only half of the second product.

Comment: Is there any consideration to use `.rankUpdate(H.adjoint());` vs `.rankUpdate(H.transpose());`? From empirical trials they both yield the same result and seem to have very similar speed performances using random data for H.