# Eigen - does matrix.transpose create a copy of the matrix?

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen3

I would like to do the following matrix product using Eigen:

```
Eigen::VectorXd vector = Eigen::VectorXd::Random(1000000); // a given long vector
Eigen::MatrixXd product = vector * vector.transpose();
```

I'm not sure Eigen will create a copy of vector when calling `vector.transpose()` or just a view. I experimented by creating a vector and its transpose then modify the value of original vector:

```
Eigen::VectorXd vector(3);
vector << 1, 2, 3;
Eigen::VectorXd vectorTranspose = vector.transpose();
vector(0) = 10;
std::cout << vector << "\n"; // shows col vector [10, 2, 3]
std::cout << vectorTranspose << "\n"; // still shows col vector [1, 2, 3]
std::cout << vector * vectorTranspose << "\n"; // this gives the error of "invalid matrix product"
std::cout << vector * vector.transpose() << "\n"; // this gives the correct behavior
```

so my questions are:

1. For a column vector with shape n by 1, why does transpose still give a column vector instead of row vector?
2. Is calling vector * vector.transpose() causing a waste due to the creation of vector.transpose() or does Eigen do something clever about it?

Comment: Looks like they provide a `transposeInPlace` option but `vector.transpose` will have to create a copy

Comment: If you want to save some memory though since you're dealing with a column vector I think a self dot product will work for you.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin what do you mean by "self dot product"? The result should be a matrix instead of a scalar.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712307/efficient-matrix-transpose-matrix-multiplication-in-eigen ?

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer just the first part (not enough reputation to simply comment).

The problem is that `vectorTranspose` is declared as `VectorXd`, which represents a **column** vector. Dynamic-size row vectors are instead of type `RowVectorXd`. Try the following:

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXd v(3);
v << 1,2,3;
Eigen::VectorXd wrong = v.transpose();
Eigen::RowVectorXd correct = v.transpose();
std::cout << "v: " << v.rows() << "x" << v.cols() << std::endl;
std::cout << "wrong: " << wrong.rows() << "x" << wrong.cols() << std::endl;
std::cout << "correct: " << correct.rows() << "x" << correct.cols() << std::endl;
```

which should print:

```
v: 3x1
wrong: 3x1
correct: 1x3
```

Eigen allows vectors to be copied in other vectors even if they have different layouts, i.e., `colVec = rowVec` will work by copying the elements of the row vector into the column vector, *without changing the layout of the column vector*. The reason why the layout of the column vector cannot change is that `VectorXd` is actually the same as `Matrix<double,Dynamic,1>`: it **must** have a single column. I believe that such "strange" copy (row into column vector and vice versa) is meant a convenience.